# How to add a Calculated field to AllContentType?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

Today, I'm having a problem is after I had created a Calculated field. It seems there is no way to add AllContentTypes. And the DefaultView, maybe I can handle this. And I also saw this method:

```
spList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(spFieldUser.SchemaXml, True, SPAddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
```

But in this case, I'm not sure I can use it or not. Because my code is:

```
                      //SPField tempSPField = spList.Fields.CreateNewField(createSPColumnObject.ColumnType, createSPColumnObject.ColumnName);//We can not use this code line for creating Calculated (there is no constructor for this)
                        SPFieldCollection collFields = spList.Fields;
                        string strSPFieldCalculatedName = collFields.Add(createSPColumnObject.ColumnName, SPFieldType.Calculated, false);
                        if (createSPColumnObject.IsAddedToDefaultView)
                        {
                            SPView spView = spList.DefaultView;
                            spView.ViewFields.Add(strSPFieldCalculatedName);
                            spView.Update();
                        }               
                        SPFieldCalculated spFieldCalculated = null;
                        //                            
                        spFieldCalculated = (SPFieldCalculated)collFields[createSPColumnObject.ColumnName];
                        spFieldCalculated.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                        //spFieldCalculated.ShowInEditForm = true;
                        spFieldCalculated.ShowInListSettings = true;
                        //spFieldCalculated.ShowInNewForm = true;
                        spFieldCalculated.ShowInViewForms = true;
                        //
                        spFieldCalculated.Description = createSPColumnObject.ColumnDescription;
                        spFieldCalculated.Formula =  string.Format(@"={0}",createSPColumnObject.CalcFormula);
                        spFieldCalculated.Update();                            
                        //spList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(spFieldCalculated.SchemaXml, createSPColumnObject.IsAddedToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);// also use this code line because we will get an exception with a duplicate column ID.

                        spFieldCalculated.OutputType = SPFieldType.Text;
                        spList.Update();
```

I totally created a Calculated column but how can I add it to allcontent types ? everybody could help me out this ? BTW, to the DefaultView, I did like the above is right ? Could eveybody let me know this ?

I just worry about everybody get misunderstanding ? Or review with missing code. So could everybody please to take a look on my code clearly ? Thanks all.

Many thanks, :)

Standley Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i fully understand what you are trying to do however i may be able to shed some light on some parts of what you are trying to do.

When you create your field does it then appear in your site actions -> site settings -> Site columns. If so you have created this correctly. If it doesn't there are hundreds of examples of how to do this if you search google.

Once you have your field create you then need to consider which content types you want to add it to. Once you have these content types you then have to add something called a field link to the Content type.

This isn't my code i have picked it off the web but this should do what you require.

```
  SPContentType ct = web.ContentTypes[contentType];
  ct.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(field));
  ct.Update();
```

Cheers
Truez

Comment: Hi Cheers Truez,  First of all, thanks for answering and following my post :)  **I think I missed a little info. That is I'm programming for creating a column with calculated field in a list not create a column for site column. 2 these stuff is different. Moreover, I also did according to above your code but could not for Calculated field. So, That is not what I'm needing.**  Many thanks to you.